# Stream API Java

Tags: java, java-stream

Как с помощью Stream Api скрыть номер телефона?
Пример: + 380 ** ** ** **3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как "правильно" реализовать с помощью Stream API я не знаю. Думаю, что никак.

Но можно, например вот так:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
String str = "+ 380 43 34 34 343";
str.chars()
            .mapToObj(i-> (index.getAndIncrement() >=  6 && index.get() < 18) 
                    && (i >= 49 && i <= 57) ? '*' : (char)i)
            .reduce(new StringBuilder(), 
                    (a, b) -> a.append(b),
                    (a,b) -> a.append(b)).toString();
```

Но, на мой взгляд, лучше всего вашу задачу решить без Stream API, например вот так:

```
String str = "+ 380 43 34 34 343";
        str = str.substring(0, 5).concat(" ** ** ** **").concat(str.substring(17,18));
```